# __USE_POSIX and VS Code in WSL distro

Tags: c, posix, signals, visual-studio-code

I'm learning C and in general I code with VS Code in Ubuntu. For convenience, I'm trying to migrate my learning materials to Windows where a lot of my other works happen, so I installed WSL 2 and its distro Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After installing VS Code for Windows and its remote extension to work with WSL, I boot up a new WSL session in VS Code, install the C/C++ extension with IntelliSense then write a simple program like below just for demonstration:

```c
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    kill(-1, SIGKILL);
}
```

The problem with VS Code is that while the program compiles, its IntelliSense doesn't detect the `kill` function in the `signal.h` header. By further investigating the header file, I observe that the following part is darkened

```c
#ifdef __USE_POSIX
extern int kill (__pid_t __pid, int __sig) __THROW;
#endif /* Use POSIX.  */
```

along with other parts where `__USE_POSIX` is checked, including but not limited to `siginfo_t`, `struct sigaction`.

Is there a way to make VS Code recognise these macros/variables to enable IntelliSense's assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You could either add `#define __USE_POSIX` above where you include the header in question, or if you want to define it as a compiler arg (Perhaps through a `-D` flag or via CMake or something), the file `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` allows you to specify which flags are being used this way like so:

```json
"configurations": [{
   "defines":["__USE_POSIX"]
}]
```

See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/304 for further information on this feature.